# Why does my Firestore document include the name of the object?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

When adding a document to **Firestore**, the record includes the object name. How can I get the elements without the object variable name?

```
this.db
    .collection('mas-people')
    .doc(rn)
    .set({ obj })
    .then(console.log('Document successfully written!'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error writing document: ', error));
```

I expect only the elements, but I am getting **"obj" + elements**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using JavaScript's new property names shorthand here `set({ obj })`, which is just shorthand for `set({ obj: obj })`.

If you just want to write the object's value, use:

```
this.db.collection("mas-people").doc(rn).set(obj)...
```